# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found IIS7 and MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I am getting the above error when I browse to the following location on my local box using Windows 7:

mysite.mobi is in my localhosts file and resolves to 127.0.0.1

This produces 404 error: http://mysite.mobi/Home/Index

This loads up ok though so IIS7 is working to some extent: http://mysite.mobi/Content/Test.htm

If I run the MVC site straight from VS2010 using the inbuilt Development server it works fine.
I copied my site into wwwroot and set-up IIS7 to point to it using AppPool with .NET4 framework and integrated pipeline.

What have I missed?  It seems like /Home/Index isn't invoking the controller for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the following section in your `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I checked and this setting is already in the web.config file.

Comment: @Yoyo, I can't remember how I fixed it but it might have something to do with setting up routing correctly.